# URL encoding error in Retrofit 2.0

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, urlencode, cfurl-encoding

```
 @GET("images")
 Call<Example> getimages(@Query("where=item_id") int item_id);
```

When I use this the equal to sign after where gets encode to %3D which my server doesn't accept.I want **=** symbol after **where** in my api call.

And my link is
images?where=item_id=1

Comment: What is your link? Is link `images?where=item_id`?

Comment: No its like images?where=item_id=1

Comment: It 's quite weird. you can try to use Path param `@GET("images?where=item_id={id}")
 Call<Example> getimages(@Path("id") int id);`

Comment: Have tried it.It throws an error mentioning to use query for dynamic url.As the item_id is dynamic.

Comment: You can replace `where=item_id` by `where%3Ditem_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
@GET("images")
Call<Example> getimages(@Query("where") String item_id);
```

When you call this method, you have to pass this way:

```
Service service = retrofit.create(Service.class);
Call<Example> call = service.getimages("item_id=1");
```

If you can call your Api successfully, you can pass the value dynamically, using string concatenation.

**Reason:** When passing query parameters you just have to write query parameter in `@Query("")` and value to it will be assigned on runtime when you will call this method and pass value to "item_id" parameter of `getimages` method.

To learn more on Retrofit, refer this link: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/tag/retrofit

Comment: Sorry but I have a where clause in between.

Comment: @Hitesh Can you post the url what actually you want to call ? Mention it in question itself.

Comment: **you have to use forward slash `/{path}`**. I use retrofit without `/` but it 's still ok.

Comment: Tried this@GET("images?where=item_id=/{item_id}")
    Call<Example> getimages(@Path("item_id")int item_id); and got the error **URL query string "where=item_id=/{item_id}" must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query.**

Comment: @ChintanSoni Nice idea.Let me implement it.

Comment: Done.Working fine.**Thank you very much.**.Would be there any issue if its compulsary to pass integer as parameter. No idea but just learned url encoding for number are same.

Answer (score 0):

Add encoded flag.

```
@GET("images")
Call<Example> getimages(@Query("where=item_id", encoded = true) String item_id);
```

and encode item_id before pass it to this method.